# Facebook page apps - liked and unliked

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I know that this has been covered in various ways before - but is there a way to display one set of content on a page for liked users and another set for people that don't like it.

This approach (http://www.uksitebuilder.net/2011/05/create-facebook-secret-fan-page/) only seems to work the first time you hit the app, so it's not good for returning visits.

I've google forever but it's very hard to find a up to date / current solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm already using the signed request, which works fine for the very first time the app is loaded in the iframe (it's not an app that requires authorization/approval - content is purely based on whether the user has 'liked' the page).

The problem I'm facing is that I need to check the 'like' status across the pages within the iframe app to confirm that they are allowed to view certain pages within it. Some links are disabled until they 'like' the page. I tried saving the signed_request in the session, but this doesn't seem to work for some members of my development team.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if user liked page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page)

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/). Simply parse the **signed request** in your Tab and read out the page.liked property. It's `true` if the user liked the page and `false` if not.

**Edit_:** After seeing your comment, just save the "liked" state in a session variable. You should then use the JavaScript methods provided by Facebook to check if the user liked the page while browsing around in your App. You could then reload the page for example. You can read about FB.Event.subscribe in the [Facebook JavaScript SDK docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).